# android:maxSDKVersion - couldn't upload apk to alpha

Tags: android, google-play, android-manifest

I've faced the problem uploading app to Play Store. The old "19" version was available for API versions 10 and above. New "20" version specified maxSDKVersion=22 (not higher Android 5.1).
An error message, when trying to upload "20", says:

> "it is forbidden that a device upgrading from API levels in the range
>   10-22 to API levels in the range of 23+ should downgrade from version
>   20 to version 19, which could happen if...".

This situation clearly specified in [documentation](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html#max):

> ...future versions of Android (beyond Android 2.0.1) will no longer 
>   check or enforce the maxSdkVersion attribute during installation or
>   re-validation. Google play will continue to use the attribute as a
>   filter, however, presenting users with applications available for
>   download.

Our application not working properly on Android 6, so we should somehow to prevent installs on those devices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, there is an answer from Google support:

> ...
>   The error message is stating that if a user updates the Android
>   version on their device, the configuration of your APKs would cause
>   them to become ineligible for the version they currently have.
>
> To resolve this issue, always make sure the APK that supports the
>   higher API level always has a higher version code. For example, if an
>   APK with API levels 14 - 17 was version 3 then an APK with API level
>   18 would have to have version 4.
>
> In other cases, you can simply remove the max SDK declaration from
>   your app’s manifest.
>   ...

And there is no way to add maxSDKVersion limitation in existing app.